# Trying to connect to MSSQL from Ubuntu PHP Server

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, ubuntu-16.04, homestead

So I've gone around in circles for a few days now and I need help.

**The setup.**

- Laravel Homestead VM
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- PHP 7.1.11-1

**The problem:**

I have a simple script setup to test a DB connection. Whenever I hit the script though and it trys I get the following error:

```
This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
```

**What I've Done:**

So, I have the latest and greatest SQL Server drivers installed. If you follow this link [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098), you'll find that when you download them, MS gives you a really good guide.  I have the extensions correctly (I think) being called from within my php.ini files (FPM, Apache2, and CLI).

Somewhere I read that there's a problem connecting to SQL Server 12. So I actually downloaded and installed a preview version of the PDO and Sqlsrv drivers that MS offered, and still same error.

Lastly, I followed this instructional guide [PHP Ubuntu MS SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/2.html) after a search, and low and behold, from the command line, using sqlcmd I can connect, but still from the script... nothing.

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: restart your web server?

Comment: I tried that a few times. No dice.

Comment: have you run `phpinfo();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php to make sure it has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

So, after running through this tut again, it's seemingly working.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/2.html

So, not exactly sure what it could be.